# Question regarding the Vietoris-Rips construction as persistent vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex, topological-data-analysis

I am currently teaching myself the basics of persistent homology by reading the following set of notes by Gunnar Carlsson.

https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/BB0DA0F0EBD79809C563AF80B555A23C/S0962492914000051a.pdf/topological_pattern_recognition_for_point_cloud_data.pdf

I first read the algebraic portion of the notes where he introduced the notion of persistent vector spaces before showing the equivalence between the isomorphism classes of finitely presented vector spaces and barcodes. Pg 316-321. I have also read the portion regarding the computation of the dimensions of the homology group of the abstract simplicial complexes. Pg 303-306

However, I am facing issues try to link the homology of the Vietoris Rips complexes to that of the finitely presented persistent vector spaces. Hence, would it be possible for someone to explain how the theory of finitely presented persistent vector spaces ties in to what is being said on Pg 315(Bottom half of page)?

Comment: You start with $X$. Consider some dimension $i$. For every $r$ you take space $V_r = H_i(\mathrm{VR}(X,r);\mathbb{R})$. This gives a persistence vector space in the sense of def 3.3. (The $L$ maps are induced by inclusion of V-R complexes).

Comment: Thanks but what is your $\rho$ here where $\rho$ is defined after remark 3.4.

Comment: I have no $\rho$. If you start with an $\mathbb{R}_+$ filtered set then $\rho$ comes as part of the data. That is a different kind of input for which persistence can also be applied.

Comment: Thanks. But what is your $\mathbb{R}_+$ filtered set in this case?

Comment: There isn't one. The (A) VR complexes of some metric space for varying $r$ give you a persistence diagram, the (B) sublevel sets of some set for varying $r$ give you a persistence diagram, but it does not mean (A) must give (B) or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks. However, the algebra portion of the notes showed a correspondence between finitely presented free persistence vector spaces and finite subsets of intervals. I am trying to see how that is related to the homology groups here. But to consider that you need to identify the finitely presented free persistence vector spaces which requires a $\rho$.

Comment: Definition 3.6 requires the notion of free persistence vector spaces which requires a $\rho$ in its definition.